# AOSP Project - how do I change the minimum length required for setting a password from 4 to 6?

Tags: android-source

I have successfully built AOSP on my Ubuntu computer and I want to do some changes on the project I work on.

One of them is, when choosing "Password" I want to change the minimum length for a password the user should set. The default AOSP sets is minimim 4 characters.

I want to change it to **6**.

I cannot find the location of where it is being set by AOSP.

Does anybody know?